# Flask & Python 3.4 - Database model errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been wrestling with the models for my app for a while now. Every time I seem to 'fix' one thing, another breaks. From Googling and searching on here I have finally come to this, however, it now throws another error I can't figure out why.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Students(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=False, unique=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=False, unique=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, id, first_name, last_name, image):
        self.id = id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.image = image

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Student: {} {}>'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    s = Students.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', Students=s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the model you will see `unique` and `primary_key` on all fields because without it I get the following error:

```
Column() missing 1 required positional argument: 'unique'
```

or

```
Column() missing 1 required positional argument: 'primary_key'
```

Now I read somewhere on here that since I'm inheriting from Models, I shouldn't have to include `__tablename__` , but without it I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class '__main__.Students'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

---

After all this I have finally come down to this error, which I'm assuming because it's saying there is no primary key?:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Students|Students could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'Students'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really know sqlalchemy, but I suspect you shouldn't be overriding the `__init__` method.

Comment: What does `pip freeze` get you?  I tried to replicate your issue with Flask==0.10.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0, and SQLAlchemy==0.9.4 but I was unable to do so (and I was able to remove the `primary_key` and `unique` keyword args from the other column declarations as well.

Comment: @SeanVieira running `pip freeze` gives me the following:


    `Flask==0.10.1
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
    Jinja2==2.7.2
    MarkupSafe==0.23
    SQLAlchemy==0.9.4
    Werkzeug==0.9.4
    itsdangerous==0.24`

Comment: You may want to remove the `.pycache` directory and any `*.pyc` files you have lying around - as it stands it looks like you and I are getting totally different results with the same code (which, while theoretically *possible* is **extremely** unlikely).